# Mark as read mail method

Tags: gmail-api

How do I mark mail as read using Gmail API?

I got the thread of email

```
Thread thread = service.users().threads().get(userId, message.getThreadId()).execute();
```

but it does not have method **markRead** like gmail API site says it should.

Comment: Where does Gmail API site say it has "method markRead"?  Are you sure you're not confusing the Gmail API with the Google Apps Scripts interface?

Gmail API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/modify

Apps Script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread

Answer (score 15):

use either threads.modify() or messages.modify() (depending on scope of what you want to do) and removeLabelId of "UNREAD".

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/modify

Answer (score 13):

In nodejs example:

```js
var google = require('googleapis');
var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);
oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
google.options({ auth: oauth2Client }); // set auth as a global default

gmail.users.messages.modify({
        'userId':'me',
        'id':emailId,
        'resource': {
            'addLabelIds':[],
            'removeLabelIds': ['UNREAD']
        }
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            error('Failed to mark email as read! Error: '+err);
            return;
        }
        log('Successfully marked email as read', emailId);
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

As I arrived here in search for this answer in C# here is the answer from my experience:

```cs
var gs = new GmailService(
                new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    ApplicationName = gmailApplicationName,
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential
                }
            );
var markAsReadRequest = new ModifyThreadRequest {RemoveLabelIds = new[] {"UNREAD"}};
                            await gs.Users.Threads.Modify(markAsReadRequest, "me", unreadMessage.ThreadId)
                                    .ExecuteAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else stumbles upon this using the Golang API. Here is how you can do it:

```golang
msg, err := gmail.Users.Messages.Modify("me", msg.Id, &gmail.ModifyMessageRequest{
   RemoveLabelIds: []string{"UNREAD"},
}).Do()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is in Java one, someone may need it.

> 1. First, you can list all labels like in example below.
>    For more information check [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/list)

```java
    public void listLabels(final Gmail service, final String userId) throws IOException {
            ListLabelsResponse response = service.users().labels().list(userId).execute();
            List<Label> labels = response.getLabels();
            for (Label label : labels) {
              System.out.println("Label: " + label.toPrettyString());
            }
          }
```

> 2. Modify the required labels for each message is associated with it, like so: More information about it goes [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify)

```java
    public void markAsRead(final Gmail service, final String userId, final String messageId) throws IOException {
            ModifyMessageRequest mods =
                    new ModifyMessageRequest()
                    .setAddLabelIds(Collections.singletonList("INBOX"))
                    .setRemoveLabelIds(Collections.singletonList("UNREAD"));
            Message message = null;
        
            if(Objects.nonNull(messageId)) {
              message = service.users().messages().modify(userId, messageId, mods).execute();
              System.out.println("Message id marked as read: " + message.getId());
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example in iOS Swift:

```swift
class func markAsReadMessage(messageId: String) {
    let appd = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    println("marking mail as read \(messageId)")
    let query = GTLQueryGmail.queryForUsersMessagesModify()
    query.identifier = messageId
    query.removeLabelIds = ["UNREAD"]
    appd.service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: { (ticket, response, error) -> Void in
        println("ticket \(ticket)")
        println("response \(response)")
        println("error \(error)")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a two steps to achieve this.  I use the Gmail Client Library, available here, specifically from the examples folder get_token.php and user-gmail.php:
[PHP Gmail Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/)

I also used the function for modification, available here:
[Gmail API Modify Message Page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify#examples)

First you must specify that you wish to have Modify rights.  In the examples, they only show you the read-only scope, but you can add other scopes in the array.

```php
$client->addScope(implode(' ', array(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY, Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_MODIFY)));
```

I wanted to keep the same labels, and mark the message as read.  So for a single message:

```php
$arrLabels = $single_message->labelIds;
foreach($arrLabels as $label_index=>$label) {
    if ($label=="UNREAD") {
        unset($arrLabels[$label_index]);
    }
}
```

Now you can send the modification request, and the message will be removed from the UNREAD list on your Gmail account.

```php
modifyMessage($service, "me", $mlist->id, $arrLabels, array("UNREAD"));
```

where "me" is the `user_id`.